# Check the value should be only 0 or 1, only using if block

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

How to print this statement without else block

```
String val ="0";
if( val.equals("0") || val.equals("1"))
{
    // Do nothing
}else{
    System.our.println("Value should be either 0 or 1");
}
```

Comment: Check the [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: Who would upvote this?? The problem is extremely trivial and the question is vaguely stated.

Comment: @Radiodef, it may be but suddenly i cant thing this logic little confused that's y i posted. now im clear...

Comment: @Paco Abato thanks now im clear...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String val ="0";
if( !val.equals("0") && !val.equals("1"))
{
   System.our.println("Value should be either 0 or 1");
}
```

Comment: if( !(val.equals("0") || val.equals("1")) also valid if you were lazy and just wanted to negate what you already had without having to think at all

Answer (score 2):

Below condition will do the trick:

```
if( !val.equals("0") && !val.equals("1"))
{
    System.our.println("Value should be either 0 or 1");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to achieve it using `||` operators as mentioned in your question, then, simply add `!` symbol in the beginning,

```
String val ="0";
if(!(val.equals("0") || val.equals("1"))){
    System.our.println("Value should be either 0 or 1");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is indeed:

```
if( !val.equals("0") && !val.equals("1"))
{
   System.our.println("Value should be either 0 or 1");
}
```

But how do you get to it? You want to enter the else branch of your statement so, you negate it.

`val.equals()` negated becomes `!val.equals()`

Logically `OR` negated becomes `AND` (and viceversa) so:  `||` becomes `&&`